# Extracting text from a PDF with Python - Highlight

Tags: python, pdf, highlight

I'm trying to code a program that extract a text from a PDF, search for key-words and highlight them, so write a new pdf with the key-words highlighted. IDK if i need to extract the text and then write a new one or if I can just highlight words without extracting them. I need to keep the text formatting, I tried to use reportlab, but it extracted the text and lost the text formatting. I'm new on programming, so maybe it's easy to solve the problem, but I dont have the skill.

I'm an electrical engineer and need to read a lot of technical specification, like IEC or NBR (Brazilian version of IEC), so if i have this code it'll help me a lot

Here is something that i code till now:

```
import PyPDF2

# Abre o arquivo PDF

pdf_file = r"C:\\Users\\pietro\\Desktop\\Projects\\espectest.pdf"

words = \["Teste"\]

# Cria um objeto PDFReader para o arquivo PDF aberto

pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_file)
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

# Pega o número de páginas do PDF

num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

# Cria uma lista zerada

pages=\[\]

# Obtém o texto da página atual do PDF

for i in range(num_pages):
page=pdf_reader.pages\[i\]
texto = pdf_reader.pages\[i\].extract_text()
pages.append(page)
pdf_writer.add_page(page)
\#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#here i need to discover how to highlight words and write them on the new file

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Imprime o texto da página atual do PDF

pdf_writer.write("especteste123.pdf")

I've tried PyPDF2, reportlab, Fitz, PDFPlumber
```

Comment: PDFs do not work that way.  What you need to do is find the location and size of the text you want, then draw a highlight rectangle as an annotation over the top of that.  https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/adding-pdf-annotations.html

Comment: Try looking at [How to Highlight and Redact Text in PDF Files with Python](https://thepythoncode.com/article/redact-and-highlight-text-in-pdf-with-python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PyMuPDF.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

my_keywords = ["kw1", "kw2", "kw3"]
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")  # the PDF
for page in doc:  # iterate over the pages
    for kw in my_keywords:  # iterate over the keywords
        rectlist = page.search_for(kw)  # locate keyword on page
        for rect in rectlist:  # iterate over its occurences
            page.add_highlight_annot(rect)  # highlight it

doc.save("output.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks Jorj McKie, it works!!! It's all about the right module.